# How to delete this space between the logo and list items in the nav bar?

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I want the navigation bar items to align left next to the logo, but am unable to achieve this.

Does anyone know what is going on?

What it looks like:
[image: as is]

The space I want gone:
[image: to be]

My HTML code:

```
<nav id="nav-bar">

<a href=""><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/7471668/logo+pic.png" id="header-img" alt="company-logo" /></a>

<ul class="nav__menu">
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="">Options</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="">How it works</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="">Sign-up</a></li
</ul>
  
</nav>
```

My CSS:

```
#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
.nav__menu {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  }
.nav__item {
  margin-right: 3rem;
  font-family: archivo;
  }
.nav-link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus-visible {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 0 -1px #FFF;
  }
#header-img {
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 0;
  }
```

Comment: This is a function of the width of the image, try changing the height not the width. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/LYzdZqd

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#nav-bar {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  }
.nav__menu {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  }
.nav__item {
  margin-right: 3rem;
  font-family: archivo;
  }
.nav-link {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus-visible {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 0 -1px #FFF;
  }
#header-img {
/* from width:25% */
  width: 100px;   /*Use px*/
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<nav id="nav-bar">

<a href=""><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/7471668/logo+pic.png" id="header-img" alt="company-logo" /></a>

<ul class="nav__menu">
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="">Options</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="">How it works</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="">Sign-up</a></li
</ul>
  
</nav>
```

I provided a snippet please do check if it is the output you are looking for.

Simply use "px" to resize the width of your image.
I changed `width: 25%;` to `width: 100px;`

Comment: Thanks this worked! I thought (assumed I guess), that width would only relate as a percentage of the image's original size...